# How to find out what assemblies an assembly references?

Tags: .net

I have an assembly (class library DLL) that references Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms.  I need to find out what version of Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms it is referencing.  Is there a tool that can do that?  Kind of like Dependency Walker for win32 dlls, but I need to get the FULL assembly reference (including the version and public key token).

The thing is my DLL is in production and all the ReportViewer DLLs are 8.0.0.0, but I am getting an error saying it can't load the 10.0.0.0 version.  So I just need a tool that will show me the full list of references that my DLL is referencing.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try with [ILSpy](http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/ILSpy.ashx), it will show the info you need. Just open the assemblies with it.

Comment: Thanks.  I had looked through ILSpy but didn't look at the References folder tree. :(

Answer (score 3):

Use ILDASM, and you will be able to see details of the assembly manifest file, which will tell you versions of referenced assemblies.